# How are containers created based on vcores and memory in MapReduce2?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I have a tiny cluster composed of 1 master (namenode, secondarynamenode, resourcemanager) and 2 slaves (datanode, nodemanager).

I have set in the yarn-site.xml of the master :

- `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb` : 512
- `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` : 1024
- `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores` : 1
- `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores` : 2

I have set in the yarn-site.xml of the slaves :

- `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` : 2048
- `yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores` : 4

Then in the master, I have set in mapred-site.xml :

- `mapreduce.map.memory.mb` : 512
- `mapreduce.map.java.opts` : -Xmx500m
- `mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores` : 1
- `mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb` : 512
- `mapreduce.reduce.java.opts` : -Xmx500m
- `mapreduce.reduce.cpu.vcores` : 1

So it is my understanding that when running a job, the mapreduce ApplicationMaster will try to create as many containers of 512 Mb and 1 vCore on both slaves, which have only 2048 Mb and 4 vCores available each, which gives space for 4 containers on each slave. This is precisely what is happening on my jobs, so no problem so far.

However, when i increment the `mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores` and `mapreduce.reduce.cpu.vcores` from 1 to 2, there should theoretically be only enough vCores available for creating 2 containers per slave right ? But no, I still have 4 containers per slave.

I then tried to increase the `mapreduce.map.memory.mb` and `mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb` from 512 to 768. This leaves space for 2 containers (2048/768=2).

**It doesn't matter if the vCores are set to 1 or 2 for mappers and reducers, this will always produce 2 containers per slave with 768mb and 4 containers with 512mb. So what are vCores for ? The ApplicationMaster doesn't seem to care.**

Also, when setting the memory to 768 and vCores to 2, I have this info displayed on nodemanager UI for a mapper container :

[image: nodemanager UI screenshot]

The 768 Mb has turned into 1024 TotalMemoryNeeded, and the 2 vCores are ignored and displayed as 1 TotalVCoresNeeded.

So to break down the "how does it work" question into multiple questions :

1. Is only memory used (and vCores ignored) to calculate the number of containers ?
2. Is the `mapreduce.map.memory.mb` value only a completely abstract value for calculating the number of containers (and that's why it can be rounded up to the next power of 2) ? Or does it represent real memory allocation in some way ?
3. Why do we specify some -Xmx value in `mapreduce.map.java.opts` ? Why doesn't yarn use the value from `mapreduce.map.memory.mb` to allocate memory to the container ?
4. What is TotalVCoresNeeded and why is it always equal to 1 ? I tried to change `mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores` in all nodes (master and slaves) but it never changes.

Comment: Do you use CapacityScheduler? If yes, can you tell me the values of following configuration parameters: yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb,  yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores,  yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb, yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores

Comment: Also, if you are using Capacity Scheduler, then my guess is, your "yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator" is set to  "org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DefaultResourceCalculator" (you are using DefaultResourceCalculator, which ignores CPU while calculating the resource requirements)

Comment: Thanks, you are right ! I didn't know that there were different resource calculators. I am now using DominantResourceCalculator in my capacity-scheduler.xml and it works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I will answer this question, on the assumption that the scheduler used is, **CapacityScheduler**.

**CapacityScheduler** uses **ResourceCalculator** for calculating the resources needed for an application. There are 2 types of resource calculators:

1. **DefaultResourceCalculator**: Takes into account, only memory for doing the resource calculations (i.e. for calculating number of containers)
2. **DominantResourceCalculator**: Takes into account, both memory and CPU for resource calculations

By default, the CapacityScheduler uses **DefaultResourceCalculator**. If you want to use the **DominantResourceCalculator**, then you need to set following property in "**capacity-scheduler.xml**" file:

```
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator</value>
  </property>
```

Now, to answer your questions:

1. If **DominantResourceCalculator** is used, then both memory and VCores are taken into account for calculating the number of containers
2. **mapreduce.map.memory.mb** is not an abstract value. It is taken into consideration while calculating the resources.

   The **DominantResourceCalculator** class has a normalize() function, which normalizes the resource request, using minimumResouce (determined by config **yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb**), maximumresource (determined by config  **yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb**) and a step factor (determined by config **yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb**).

   The code for normalizing memory looks like below (Check org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator.java):

   ```
   int normalizedMemory = Math.min(roundUp(
   Math.max(r.getMemory(), minimumResource.getMemory()),
   stepFactor.getMemory()),maximumResource.getMemory());
   ```

Where:

r = Requested memory

The logic works like below:

a. Take max of(requested resource and minimum resource) = max(768, 512)  = 768

b. roundup(768, StepFactor) =  roundUp (768, 512) == 1279 (Approximately)

```
Roundup does : ((768 + (512 -1)) / 512) * 512
```

c. min(roundup(512, stepFactor), maximumresource) = min(1279, 1024) = 1024

So finally, the allotted memory is 1024 MB, which is what you are getting.

For the sake of simplicity, you can say that roundup, increments the demand in the steps of 512 MB (which is a minimumresource)

3. Since Mapper is a java process, **mapreduce.map.java.opts** is used for specifying the heap size for the mapper.

Where as **mapreduce.map.memory.mb** is total memory used by the container.

Value of **mapreduce.map.java.opts** should be lesser than **mapreduce.map.memory.mb**

The answer here explains that: [What is the relation between 'mapreduce.map.memory.mb' and 'mapred.map.child.java.opts' in Apache Hadoop YARN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070557/what-is-the-relation-between-mapreduce-map-memory-mb-and-mapred-map-child-jav)

4. When you use **DominantResourceCalculator**, it uses normalize() function to calculate vCores needed.

   The code for that is (similar to normalization of memory):

   ```
     int normalizedCores = Math.min(roundUp  
   `   Math.max(r.getVirtualCores(), minimumResource.getVirtualCores()), 
       stepFactor.getVirtualCores()), maximumResource.getVirtualCores());
   ```