# Hadoop streaming "GC overhead limit exceeded"

Tags: hadoop, out-of-memory, hadoop-streaming

I am running this command:

```
hadoop jar hadoop-streaming.jar -D stream.tmpdir=/tmp -input "<input dir>"  -output "<output dir>" -mapper "grep 20151026" -reducer "wc -l"
```

Where `<input dir>` is a directory with many `avro` files.

And getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead
>   limit exceeded    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.DatanodeID.updateXferAddrAndInvalidateHashCode(DatanodeID.java:287)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.DatanodeID.(DatanodeID.java:91)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.DatanodeInfo.(DatanodeInfo.java:136)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.DatanodeInfo.(DatanodeInfo.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.convert(PBHelper.java:633)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.convert(PBHelper.java:793)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.convertLocatedBlock(PBHelper.java:1252)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.convert(PBHelper.java:1270)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.convert(PBHelper.java:1413)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.convert(PBHelper.java:1524)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.convert(PBHelper.java:1533)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getListing(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:557)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.getListing(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.listPaths(DFSClient.java:1969)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$DirListingIterator.hasNextNoFilter(DistributedFileSystem.java:888)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$DirListingIterator.hasNext(DistributedFileSystem.java:863)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:267)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:228)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:313)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeOldSplits(JobSubmitter.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:616)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:492)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)

How can this issue be resolved ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took a while, but I found the solution [here](http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-Processing-and-Workflow/cloudera-hadoop-mapreduce-job-GC-overhead-limit-exceeded-error/td-p/14754).

Prepending `HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Xmx1024M"` to the command solves the problem.

The final commandline is:

```
HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Xmx1024M" hadoop jar hadoop-streaming.jar -D stream.tmpdir=/tmp -input "<input dir>"  -output "<output dir>" -mapper "grep 20151026" -reducer "wc -l"
```